# Server Error on second reload

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

After some time I always get an internal server error 500 when reloading the page a second time.

- Clearing the cache fixes to problem for about 10 hours
- Switching the browser lets me again load the page, gives me the error on second reload

Caching is not enabled for the search action.
Only one module is affected, other modules work during the time the site is down.

Any ideas where to look? The symfony error logs are not really helpful the request does not even reach symfony.

Comment: What does your web server's error log say?

Comment: Check Apache's error log then.

Comment: You should consider turning display_errors on too http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors

Comment: Some errors about missing routes but these are happening all the time (not my work)
A lot of errors because of strange sf_cultures (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330962/symfony-sf-culture-1-error) 

All this errors are not specific to the time before the site goes down.

Comment: Is the entire module down for everyone, or just for a single user/session?

Comment: Only the search page is down, more precisely there is a internal server error 500 after executeSearch is invoked. 
Other users/sessions can perform the search once but not a second time, after that search stays down for this user/session too, until I clear the cache. 
Nobody I talked to (in our it department) could find the error looking at various log files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be related to route caching.  Try disabling your route cache in factories.yml and see if this helps.

For Example:

```
  routing:
    class: sfPatternRouting
    param:
      load_configuration:               true
      suffix:                           ''
      default_module:                   default
      default_action:                   index
      debug:                            %SF_DEBUG%
      logging:                          %SF_LOGGING_ENABLED%
      generate_shortest_url:            true
      extra_parameters_as_query_string: true
      cache:                            ~
```